# Some basic questions about weak-metrizable subsets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Sorry to bother but I'm having some problems proving some properties in my way to prove some others weak and weak-* metrizability properties.

**First**
If I got a Banach space $X$, wich its dual $X^{*}$ is separable. Then the closed unit ball of the dual is separable with respect to the norm of $X^{*}$ which is the usual.

In this case, I think I have to find a dense and countable family which fulfills what we need

**Second**
Once we prove the above statement, lets suppose that the countable dense family we found is $\phi$ contained in the closed unit ball of the dual. Then if we define:

$d(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 2^{-k}|\phi_{k}(x-y)|$ for $x,y\in X$

Im having problems proving that is in fact a metric. In particular, I'm struggling with the implication $d(x,y)=0 \implies x=y$.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(\phi_k)$ be dense in the unit ball of the dual  w.r.t. weak* topology. Then $d(x,y)=0$ implies $\phi_k( x)=\phi_k(y)$ for all $k$. This implies $\phi (x)=\phi(y)$ for every $\phi $ in the unit ball of the dual  hence for every $\phi$ in the dual space. This implies $x=y$ because $x-y \neq 0$ implies that there exists $\phi$ with $\phi(x-y) \neq 0$. [This is a consequence of Hahn Banach Theorem].

Comment: Thanks sir, and with respect to the first question, could you help me to elaborate an answer? Cause I know I could find $\phi_{k}=\mu_{k}$ when $||\mu_{k}||\leq 1$ and $\frac{\mu_{k}}{||\mu_{k}||}$ when $||\mu_{k}||>1$ but I haven't been able to use it to show that the unit ball   is in fact separable in the norm of the dual :/

Comment: Any subset of a separable metric space is separable. So if the dual space is separable so is the closed unit ball. @skt1o2